# Please vote to reopen the "facebook" etymology question

Tags: discussion

[Origin of the word "facebook"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250445/origin-of-the-word-facebook/250446#250446)

Research is included now (close reason was lack of research) and it is a good question with good answers.

OP didn't directly asked the origin of "Facebook" (the company name). He asked about the noun *facebook*.

Also, Etymonline is sometimes missed even if you do some research. There are examples of this in the past and those questions are not close-voted.

Comment: two more needed...

Comment: Reopened. Thanks for adding the research for the OP. (I'm surprised OED doesn't have it -- I checked myself as well -- and that Google's "case-insensitive" Ngram search is anything but.)